# Copy data from Azure databricks to AWS Ec2

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am new to Azure Databricks. I want to copy data from azure databricks to one of my aws ec2 instance. can anyone please help me in doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use tools like `azcopy` or `aws`, with a destination link to move your data.

Edit: other option is to mount the bucket on your databricks (see [link](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html)) and copy the data (you can look at [an article I made](https://medium.com/@robin.loche/efficient-file-manipulation-with-databricks-9eb9301bf833) for efficient copy).